# How can I listen to incoming query to SQL Server with a TCP Server built with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, sockets, tcp

I created a TCP Server and TCP Client for testing with ASP.NET Core.

This is my TCP Server:

```
public class TCPServer
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Start the server  
        TCPHelper.StartServer(5678);
        TCPHelper.Listen(); // Start listening.  
    }
}
```

Here are my functions in the TCP Helper I use:

```
class TCPHelper
{
    private static TcpListener listener { get; set; }
    private static bool accept { get; set; } = false;

    public static void StartServer(int port)
    {
        IPAddress localAdd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localAdd, port);
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
        listener.Start();

        //---incoming client connected---
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

        //---get the incoming data through a network stream---
        NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];

        //---read incoming stream---
        int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

        //---convert the data received into a string---
        string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        Console.WriteLine("Received : " + dataReceived);

        //---write back the text to the client---
        Console.WriteLine("Sending back : " + dataReceived);
        nwStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        client.Close();
        listener.Stop();
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine($"Server started. Listening to TCP clients at 127.0.0.1:{port}");
    }

    public static void Listen()
    {
        if (listener != null && accept)
        {
            // Continue listening.  
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client...");
                var clientTask = listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(); // Get the client  

                if (clientTask.Result != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Client connected. Waiting for data.");
                    var client = clientTask.Result;

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the TCP CLient side and my main problem is actually in this part:

```
public class TCPClient
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //I am trying to connect to Tcp Server with connection string.

        var conn_string= "server=tcp:127.0.0.1, 5678;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=120;";
        
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn_string))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
     }
}
```

The first part of the Connection String is the information of my TCP Server that I broadcast, I want to specify the connection string in this way and connect to SQL Server as if my customers are connecting to my TCP Server and then read the SQL queries they will make.

So I want to use TCP Server as a layer between the client and SQL Server, but my clients must think they are connecting to SQL Server.

When I run this code, I get an error like this:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)'

And in the terminal of my TCP Server it reads something like:

[image]

I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: In your OP, you stated: _my clients must think they are connecting to Sql_. Is this what you're trying to achieve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack

Comment: Maybe it is better to capture the ExecuteQuery than to do it at TCP level.

Comment: What are you really trying to do here?  Why are you going through all the trouble of creating a SQL Server proxy service (I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that it's not actually a man-in-the-middle, for now)?  You can enable tracing on your SQL Server instance and get all this information from DMV's, extended events, traces, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry if I explained myself wrong with my English. I'm trying to provide data security for people with sql access

Comment: It's really not your english that is the question here, it's the solution you're trying to build. `"...provide data security..."`  What is lacking in SQL Server's robust security architecture that makes it so that you need to build something like this?

Comment: As you said, I am trying to do this work with TCP, which can also be done with TSql. Because I don't know TSql. That's why I posted the question.

Comment: With all due respect, if you don't know t-sql then you really shouldn't be providing a security mechanism for SQL Server.  You really should be doing this within SQL Server.  Spend the time to learn and develop a proper solution.